# что делать с кучей событий

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Я новичок в web и не знаю что делать когда на одной странице есть несколько кнопок и каждую надо закрывать при клике на пустое место. Мне не очень хочется писать столько событий на document, сколько кнопок. Может как-то создавать событие при открытии меню и удалять после закрытия. В общем прошу совета на js или jquery.

Comment: набирайтесь опыта, и не торопитесь.

Comment: Почитайте про [делегирование событий](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

Comment: @EzioMercer кнопки находятся в разных местах и каждую надо закрывать при клике вне кнопки. мне ведь не вешать общий обработчик на document и потом через if каждую кнопку обрабатывать

Comment: Ну задайте общий класс для таких кнопок и при клике просто смотрите на наличие класса. Вешать можно хоть на `document` хоть на общий родительский элемент

Comment: @EzioMercer тоесть при клике куда либо в обработчике проверять имеет ли она, общий для кнопок, класс и если имеет, то что. у каждой кнопки ведь своя логика. сейчас у меня есть обработчик на общего родителя и внутри 5 if для каждой кнопки

Comment: Какая разница какая логика у кнопки? Вам же просто надо их скрыть, разве нет? Это же просто `display: none`